# the effect of aquatic photoautotrophs on CO2 concentration in the air

Tags: ecology, environment

The CO2 concentration in the air is more strongly influenced by the northern hemisphere than the southern hemisphere. A given explanation is that the northern hemisphere contains more terrestrial photoautotrophs. Does that mean that the effect of aquatic photoautotrophs on the CO2 concentration is much weaker than that of terrestrial photoautotrophs? If so, how is it so?

[image]

Comment: the obvious guess would be that it's because the terrestrial autotrophs affect the atmosphere directly while aquatic ones can only directly affect CO2 in the ocean; and mixing between the ocean and atmosphere is much slower than mixing within the atmosphere itself

Comment: @timeskull i guess guessing is the least usefull thing one can do on a science site.